# Does MySQL have 13-bit timestamp column type?

Tags: mysql

I migrate data from PostgreSQL to MySQL and find an interesting stuff on timestamp:

The original time data stored in PS is shown as: `2019-12-29 15:59:59.921`, when transferred to MySQL, it automatically becomes:`2019-12-29 16:00:00`. I tried both `timestamp` and `datetime` column types but still the same result. It seems only the initial 10-bit timestamp is processed by MySQL.

The time will be added 8 hours so this could lead to different dates. So how to address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL since version 5.7 supports fractional seconds in timestamps. They're not on-by-default and need to use `TIMESTAMP(3)` when defining a column as an example for milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for milli seconds, need to alter table and have the `TimeStamp(6)`.

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`sometable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` `timestamp` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```